# what does template<> (without any class T in the <>) mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading some source code in stl_construct.h,
In most cases it has sth in the <>
and i see some lines with only "`template<> ...`".
what's this?

Answer (score 10):

This would mean that what follows is a [template specialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Guess, I completely misread the Q and answered something that was not being asked.
So here I answer the Q being asked:

It is an **[Explicit Specialization](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/explicit_specialization.htm) with an empty template argument list.**

When you instantiate a template with a given set of template arguments the compiler generates a new definition based on those template arguments. But there is a facility to override this behavior of definition generation. Instead of compiler generating the definition We can specify the definition the compiler should use for a given set of template arguments. This is called **explicit specialization**.

The `template<>` prefix indicates that the following template declaration takes no template parameters.

Explicit specialization can be applied to:

- Function or class template
- Member function of a class template
- Static data member of a class template
- Member class of a class template
- Member function template of a class template &
- Member class template of a class template

Answer (score 0):

It's a template specialization where all template parameters are fully specified, and there happens to be no parameters left in the `<>`.

For example:

```
template<class A, class B>   // base template
struct Something
{ 
    // do something here
};

template<class A>            // specialize for B = int
struct Something<A, int>
{ 
    // do something different here
};

template<>                   // specialize both parameters
struct Something<double, int>
{ 
    // do something here too
};
```